# PyQt4: Trigger click on a javascript link

Tags: javascript, python, webkit, pyqt, qwebview

I am trying to scrape some web pages in Python were the information is generated by Javascript.

I managed to retrieve the information generated on page load by using a headless browser with PyQt4 (example here: http://blog.motane.lu/2009/07/07/downloading-a-pages-content-with-python-and-webkit/)

But now, I'm trying to retrieve some information that is generated by having the user click on a Javascript link.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need [Form Extractor Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/webkit-formextractor.html). The trick is that you can expose any python object to javascript and call its methods. Pytonic version of this example could be found in PyQt distribution.